# GEF - How to open GEF application on ViewPart application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I am newbe in GEF development.
I had created one GEF application using Draw2D apis.
Application contains Two tree viewers. I need to draw connection to connect children of these trees. I also want to keep control on these connection so that I can able to delete them. I need to draw 1-1 and N-1 kind of connections.
I need to embed this application within an RCP application which I already have and want to show it as a view within my specific Perspective.

Additionally, I have my own data model.
I want to know that to convert my model to GEF understandable model format what changes do I need to make with my model.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to essentially do is create an Eclipse modeling project. The way it works is by creating your own EMF models. All your tree nodes with their attributes are "modelled" in EMF.

Then you can convert this model to an GEF/Draw2d Diagram using something called GMF(Graphical Modeling Framework).

**EMF :**

> The EMF project is a modeling framework and code generation facility
>   for building tools and other applications based on a structured data
>   model. From a model specification described in XMI, EMF provides tools
>   and runtime support to produce a set of Java classes for the model,
>   along with a set of adapter classes that enable viewing and
>   command-based editing of the model, and a basic editor.

http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/

**GMF :**

> The GMF Tooling project provides a model-driven approach to generating
>   graphical editors in Eclipse.

http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/?project=gmf-tooling

**Tutorial :** 
I would suggest looking at the following tutorial to get a feel of the whole thing.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-gmf/

Comment: Hello @Apache, Thank you for the reply. I want to develop one application which will contains 2 tree's with some attributes. I want to allow user to join these attributes with arrows drawn using drag and drop. They can have 1-1 and N-1 kind of relationships. I want to ask which tool I can use among Graphiti, EMF or GEF. . .  I am totally confused. Additionally I had developed similar type of application developed using RCP. I want to deliver this graphical solution as a additional view within same perspective. Your suggestion is highly appreciated. Regards, Mandar